# MongoDB - Filter subdocuments by value in these

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544638f66ffd8c580e000003"),
    "Cars" : {
        "title" : "Xe ô tô",
        "category" : "53f5cce56ffd8cd415000003",
        "show" : "1",
        "action" : {
            "manager" : {
                "title" : "Xe",
                "show" : "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "Hotels" : {
        "title" : "Khách sạn",
        "category" : "53f5c88a6ffd8cd415000002",
        "show" : "1",
        "action" : {
            "manager_index" : {
                "title" : "Xem",
                "show" : "1"
            },
            "manager_setup_room" : {
                "title" : "Cài đặt phòng",
                "show" : "1"
            },
            "manager_rating" : {
                "title" : "Đánh giá",
                "show" : "1"
            },
            "manager_add" : {
                "title" : "Thêm",
                "show" : "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "OrderHotels" : {
        "title" : "",
        "category" : "540927688621afac17000000",
        "show" : "0",
        "action" : {
            "manager" : {
                "title" : "",
                "show" : "0"
            }
        }
    },
    "Roles" : {
        "title" : "",
        "category" : "540927688621afac17000000",
        "show" : "0",
        "action" : {
            "manager_hotel" : {
                "title" : "",
                "show" : "0"
            }
        }
    },
    "Users" : {
        "title" : "",
        "category" : "540927688621afac17000000",
        "show" : "0",
        "action" : {
            "manager_index" : {
                "title" : "",
                "show" : "0"
            },
            "manager_add" : {
                "title" : "",
                "show" : "0"
            },
            "manager_delete" : {
                "title" : "",
                "show" : "0"
            },
            "manager" : {
                "title" : "",
                "show" : "0"
            }
        }
    },
    "modified" : ISODate("2014-10-22T02:40:58.000Z"),
    "created" : ISODate("2014-10-21T10:44:06.000Z"),
}
```

I want to only show objects with same category (inside it), for example:

- 53f5cce56ffd8cd415000003: Cars, CarType,...
- 53f5cce56ffd8cd415000004: Hotel, Room,...

Help me solve it!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you give a clearer explanation? Where do CarType and Room come from?

Comment: It's my example, sorry :)). You can see Hotels and OrderHotels have the same category (category is a field of them) and I want to filter them.

The document I posted is a record of table!